# What is glVertexAttribPointerData

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, trace

I googled it, but could not find any useful info. What is this function? I saw this function in a trace file created with Tracer for OpenGL ES (a tool that is available in Android SDK, needs Android 4.1 (API Level 16) or higher).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a helper function used by the tracer to send the data corresponding to `glVertexAttribPointer`. `glVertexAttribPointer` provides a pointer into user memory, and it is not possible to determine at the point of the call how much data should be read out of that client memory. This is only known with a subsequent `glDraw` call, and so at that point the tracer reads the data and sends it to the host.

Answer (score 0):

My bet would be, that this is only a helper function, that gives information about the data which was used in a previous call of glVertexAttribPointer without VBO.

If so, this is a strange behaviour since the tracer should show only OpenGL functions (at least I saw only standard OpenGL function calls except the one in question).

Could anyone confirm or deny my tip?